# CSRF with OAuth or Bearer Authorization headers

Tags: attack-prevention, csrf, authorization

I am designing a RESTful API which is to be accessible from a web browser. The API is protected by Basic authentication.

I understand the concept of CSRF, and the mitigations proposed (I found both [Wikipedia CSRF entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) and [OWASP CSRF page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) good explanations). They generally introduce some state that the client needs to keep and present back to the server, so the server knows requests still come from the right client.

I am facing, though, that the client implementation becomes very "dirty" because of that and I was wondering if there could be cleaner solutions. Specifically, one that would not require handling additional state.

One solution I am thinking of, but wanted to check out with you, is to use some `Authorization` header that is not `Basic`.

According to RFC 2617, section 2, regarding `Basic` authentication scheme, the username and password may be cached by the browser and re-sent without asking to the user under certain conditions, and that's what it makes it vulnerable to CSRF:

```
A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of
the current challenge. A client MAY preemptively send the
corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in
that space without receipt of another challenge from the server.
```

I also verified that `Authorization: OAuth` (used in OAuth 1.0 authenticated endpoints) and `Authorization: Bearer` (used in OAuth 2.0 authenticated endpoints) are not automatically sent by the browser.

So, my question is: would you consider that an endpoint protected by OAuth/Bearer authorization headers should take additional precautions to prevent CSRF?

Comment: I can't work out what you're asking for.  You struggle with passing a CSRF token around.  Surely you still have to pass session information around with OAuth.  (You specifically _don't_ want the browser to handle it automatically).  Also, XHR draft spec suggests (though I have not tested) you could set an `Authorization: Basic` header manually; the browser wouldn't cache that.

Comment: Yes @sourcejedi I believe passing the OAuth token is less complex than a variable token that changes often. Also, most often those tokens are passed as GET/POST parameters, which makes the API dirtier.

Answer (score 14):

As long as you are not using using a built-in browser authentication scheme like `Basic` (or client certificates, digest, NTLM in some browsers, etc) or cookie authentication for your API you do not need to worry about CSRF.

Comment: This is what I believe, however, how can I validate that assumption? Is there a specification for that?

Comment: No spec that I know of states this explicitly, but OAuth 2.0 relies on this assumption, and it is used extensively.

Comment: Digest authentication, ntlm, negotiate and certificate auth are vulnerable to crsf and these aren't basic or cookie so it is wrong to say that. Just a note for others that may stumble across this answer, but if you could edit it that would be great.

Comment: Note, that restricting redirect url on authorization server is wise, due to referrer header thing. https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-06.html